# Navigate inside collapse menu with HREF tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a collapsible div, using javascript, where you can navigate and open the collapsible by using the href="#one" tag. I have tried putting the href inside of the div, but with no result. I've also tried making the

inside the div to an anchor text but still no success. However I do the collapsable won't open on the tag, only navigate to it's area while still being hidden.

```
<div class="box" id="one "> <h1> Object One </h1> </div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible" > <a href="#one"> Read more </a> </button>
<div class="content" href="#one"> 

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi
pisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid
unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mini
m veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

</div>
```

javascript

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {

coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

this.classList.toggle("active");

var content = this.nextElementSibling;

if (content.style.display === "block") 
{
content.style.display = "none";
} else {
content.style.display = "block";
}
});
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wbyux172/1/

Hope I can get some help with this one :)

Comment: You can not nest `a` into `button`, that is invalid HTML to begin with. Divs don’t have a `href` attribute. And I don’t see what the relevance of that attribute is supposed to be here in the first place? You are not using it to select any elements by.

Comment: Yes I have understood this, that is why it is not working. The question is: what is the correct way to do this? How do I make so when someone visits website.com/#one they get navigated to an collapsed (opened) div?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **link** to a **named anchor** by using the **name** attribute (or the **id** attribute).

When linking within the same document, the A element is set as follows.

```
<a href="#anchorname">linked text</a>

(Target point)
<a name="anchorname">a named anchor</a>
```

[click here](http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name.html) to see working example with explanation.

**Checkout this working example:**

```js
var cols = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
cols.forEach((col) => {
  col.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var contentArea = this.nextElementSibling;
    var content = contentArea.querySelector('.content');
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.collapsible a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-area .content {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="one "><h1>Object One</h1></div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible" >
  <a href="#section1">Read more</a>
</button>
<div class="content-area">
  <a name="section1"></a>
  <div class="content">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi
  pisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid
  unt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mini
  m veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think you misunderstood what I was aiming for :) The code you sent is for a collapsible, which I know how to get working. The functionality I am having trouble with is adding so when you visit for example website.com/#one you get directed to the collapsible that is collapsed (open). I can get it working with making it navigate to the box-div but not also having the collapsible be open. Do you know a way to do this? :)

Comment: @benimsson Yea, Got it. I know the answer, I will update the example.

Comment: @benimsson I have updated the example, check if this helps you to resolve your issue.